# Selected image won't change previously displayed image

Tags: swift, xcode, image

I've got a simple set up to select an image from either camera or photo library.  When I select a new photo, it doesn't change from the original photo that the app loads with.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the hierarchy (not sure if I'm using that in correct terms) of the code.  I read my code as the image I select, I then set the variable "originalImage" to the selected image.  So that should display right? Well, spoiler, I'm wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var originalImage = UIImage(named: "crossSection2.jpg")!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = originalImage
    }
    @IBAction func onCameraClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.showPicker(sourceType: .camera)
        }))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            self.showPicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary)
            }))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage newImage : UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.originalImage = newImage
        self.imageView.image = newImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619152-imagepickercontroller

> Deprecated Use imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
>   instead.

so, try changing your code to:

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.originalImage = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
        self.imageView.image = (info[.originalImage] as! UIImage)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that was it! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your UIImageView, not only "originalImage". Try:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage newImage : UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.originalImage = newImage
    self.imageView.image = newImage
}
```

Comment: That would make sense wouldn't it.  I happened to try that a little after asking the question and it still didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice this previously.  I'm getting a layout constraint error in the console.   ```[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000037cdc0 UIView:0x7fe7d410c4b0.width == - 16   (active)>"
)``` I took out the constraint, ran it, updated it, ran it, neither worked.

Comment: Am I not supposed to use the safe area?  I have all four constraints set to 0.  Not sure why I still get that error.